# Google Cloud NL : ImportError

Tags: python, importerror, google-cloud-nl

I am getting this error message with Google Cloud NL Api.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c22ac635f054> in <module>
      1 # Imports the Google Cloud client library
----> 2 from google.cloud import language
      3 from google.cloud.language import enums
      4 from google.cloud.language import types
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'language' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I tried to re-install google cloud language.

This command is working from the terminal (I get a result)

```
gcloud ml language analyze-entities --content="Michelangelo Caravaggio, Italian painter, is known for 'The Calling of Saint Matthew'."
```

I don't think I'm using any virtual environment.

I'm wondering is the library is installed at the right location, but I don't know how to make sure?

Comment: `pip install google-cloud-language`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that already. It makes no difference. How can check if it's installed in the right location?

Comment: `from google.cloud import language; language.__file__`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it says here that you're supposed to install this library in a virtual environment:

https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-language/

(note: remove all the < >, and no "" needed)

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-language
```

Then if you're using Jupyter Notebook you can just follow these instructions:

https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/

At the end I restarted the Jupyter from a new terminal window.
And from the menu I chose kernel / change kernel / "name of your environment"
And it worked!